# How to smoothly animate a marker in google maps API with Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have managed to display a marker on the map in the current position and everytime I'm moving the camera is following me. I get the device current location every 1000 milliseconds like this:

```
LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
locationRequest.setInterval(1000);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

When I'm using my app inside my car, my current location update is not animating like Google Map app does, is jumping from one point to another.

How can I get a smooth animation when the current location is changing? I'm not interested in having a method that uses a `LatLng startPosition` and a `LatLng destination`, I just want to have a nice user experience when moving.

This my method that helps me move the camera:

```
private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom) {
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
}
```

Comment: please post your current code of moveCamera

Comment: @CaoMinhVu Thanks for replying. Just updated my question.

Comment: Sound like you want to `map.setmylocationenabled(true)`. This enables the location layer.  You can use the My Location layer and the My Location button to show your user their current position on the map.

Comment: @thelastchief I'm already using `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` but it doesn't provide me the smooth movement that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code instead to animate the camera:

```
CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
        if(mMap != null) {
            mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        }
```

Comment: I'll try it, thanks. Is there any way I can test this without driving my car?

Comment: Yes, using this application, you can fake any location:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.msl.worldtroll

Comment: I didn't make it work with that simulator but I tried another and it works perfectly. This is the right answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraIdle() {
                    CameraPosition position = mMap.getCameraPosition();
                     mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mCurrentLatitude, mCurrentLongitude), 12.0f));
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but why should I use `setOnCameraIdleListener`?

Comment: move camera will continuous make call to get map marker so it get hang or slow rendering, so when it in ideal stage you can make the request for better rendering

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try it. Is there any way I can test this without driving my car?